# Map Collections in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, collections

I am coming from a JavaScript background, and in JS we can map/change an array easily.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var doubled = arr.map(function(c) { 
    return c * 2;
});

console.log(doubled); //[2,4,6,8]
```

Is something like that in Java?

Comment: Yes - see Java 8 streams: http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely:

```
Integer arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Arrays.stream(arr).map(i -> i * 2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that this is not changing the original array. It creates a stream out of the source array, creates another stream by applying the map function and executes the `println` of `System.out` for each element of the stream.

Use

```
Integer newArr[] = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(i -> i * 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toArray(new Integer[arr.length]);
```

to collect the elements of the resulting stream into an array of `Integer`s.

**EDIT**: if you're using primitive types, there's a more efficient way to do it:

```
int[] intArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] newIntArr = Arrays.stream(intArr).map(i -> i * 2).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
List<Integer> dbl = arr
        .stream()
        .map(a -> a * 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with a stream.

```
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Integer[] doubled = (Integer[]) Arrays.stream(array).map(i -> i * 2).toArray();
```

The above code will map the original array to a new array where each value is doubled.